# Отступ под футером

Tags: css3, html5

Появляется отступ под футером. Пытался гуглить, но если находил, то не работало.

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example | Example</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" src="favicon.ico">
        <style>
         .header { position: relative;
         margin-left: -10px;
         margin-right: -10px;
         background-color: black;
         margin-top: -10px; }
         .header-text-block { position: relative;
         color: white;
         padding-top: 15px;
         padding-bottom: 15px;
         margin-right: 15px;
         margin-left: 15px; }
         .header-text { margin-right: 15px;
         font-size: 35px;
         text-align: right;
         margin-top: -75px;
         font-family: Andale Mono, monospace; }
         .img-header { width: 40px;
         transition: 0.5s ease-in-out; }
         .img-header:hover { transform: scale(1.2); }
         body { background-color: orange; }
         .body { background-color: white;
         margin-left: 5%;
         margin-right: 5%; }
         .content-on-body { margin-left: 15px;
         margin-right: 15px;
         padding-top: 1px;
         padding-bottom: 1px; }
         .footer { position: relative;
         margin-left: -10px;
         margin-right: -10px;
         margin-top: -22px;
         background-color: black; }
         .text-on-footer { padding-top: 15px;
         padding-bottom: 15px;
         margin-left: 15px;
         font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
         color: white;
         line-height: 35px;
         font-weight: 400; }
         .menu { position: absolute;
         display: none;
         visibility: hidden;
         background-color: black;
         color: white;
         margin-left: -13px;
         margin-top: 5px;
         opacity: 0; }
         .navicon:hover .menu { display: block;
         visibility: visible;
         transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
         opacity: 1; }
         .links { margin: 5px;
         transition: 0.5s;
         color: white;
         font-size: 50px; }
         .links:hover { background-color: grey; }
         a { text-decoration: none; }
         .nav-on-pc { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
         /* Оптимизация сайта */
         @media (min-width: 731px) { .img-header { display: none; visibility: hidden; } .nav-on-pc { display: inline-block; visibility: visible; } .links { font-size: 15px; display: inline; } .header-text { margin-top: -20px; font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 0px; } .text-on-footer { font-size: 15px; line-height: 25px; } .body { margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; } }
         @media (max-width: 730px) { .img-header { width: 40px; } .header-text { margin-top: -40px; font-size: 25px; margin-bottom: 5px; } .links { font-size: 20px; } }
        </style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
     <header class="header">
       <div  class="header-text-block">
        <div class="navicon" style="display: inline;"><img src="navicon.png" class="img-header"><div class="menu">
          <a href="lorem.html">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
          <a href="lorem.html">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
          <a href="lorem.html">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
          <a href="lorem.html">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
          <a href="lorem">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
     </div></div>
        <div class="nav-on-pc">
          <a href="lorem.html">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
          <a href="lorem.html">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
          <a href="lorem.html">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
          <a href="lorem.html">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
          <a href="lorem">
           <div class="links">lorem</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <h1 class="header-text">lorem</h1>
       </div>
     </header>
     <div class="body">
      <div class="content-on-body">
       <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h2>
      </div>
     </div>
     <footer class="footer">
      <div>
       <h2 class="text-on-footer">E-mail: LoremIpsum@dolor.sit<br>Телефон: +012345678901</h2>
      </div>
     </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Игорь, здравствуйте! Если я Вас правильно понял, то вам нужно добавить для тэга BODY margin: 0; Так как например browser yandex и мн.др по умолчанию подставляют отступ для этого тэга.

Comment: Сразу не обратил внимание, но вы пишите так : .body (с точкой), соответственно вы привязываете стили к классу body не к тэгу. Вам тогда нужно добавить class в тэге body. Так <body class="body">. Или в стилях убрать точку перед body. Вот так:
body {margin: 0} - привязка стилей к тэгу, 
.body {margin: 0;} - привязка к классу